# Issue on Connection with Cordapp to Springboot

Tags: frontend, rpc, corda

I am new to Springboot. Currently, I am working on Corda Blockchain, I am facing some issues in connecting my cordapp through spring-boot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk6lg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlXqN.jpg)

If anyone have any reference or solution,kindly share it help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't set the values inside `NodeRPCConnection`; see example here:
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/clients/src/main/kotlin/com/example/server/NodeRPCConnection.kt
2. They are injected when you run one of the `runPartyServer` gradle tasks:
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/cordapp-example/clients/build.gradle
3. For example to start PartyA webserver, all you have to do is type: `./gradlew runPartyAServer`.

Obviously, you must first start your node then run the webserver.